# How to format an NFC tag in NDEF format

Tags: android, nfc

I've a Mifare Classic1K NFC tag but I'm unable to write any content over it. Its writable but seems like it is not formatted in NDEF which is a pre-requisite for Android devices to be write data on it. Any suggestion is welcome.

P.S: I do have a TRF7960 RF Antenna if that can help to format it.

Comment: Make sure the Android phone you are using a phone that can read Mifare Classic tags. Android supports it, but not all Android phones do due to licensing issues.

Answer (score 8):

Given an `android.nfc.Tag` object named `tag`, to format it, use:

```
    NdefFormatable formatable=NdefFormatable.get(tag);

    if (formatable != null) {
      try {
        formatable.connect();

        try {
          formatable.format(msg);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
          // let the user know the tag refused to format
        }
      }
      catch (Exception e) {
        // let the user know the tag refused to connect
      }
      finally {
        formatable.close();
      }
    }
    else {
      // let the user know the tag cannot be formatted
    }
```

Comment: Will this code be able to format it even if its not in NDEF format right now?

Comment: @pansp: If the tag is NDEF-formattable, yes. Not shown is code to detect whether or not it is already in NDEF format. You can see the full sample project I pulled this from here: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/NFC/SecretAgentMan

Comment: @CommonsWare its not working. I'm getting formatting value null. Please alternatively suggest

Comment: @AristoMichael: I do not know of any other way to format an NFC tag, sorry.

Comment: @CommonsWare my tag is formatable i.e., `formatable != null (true)` but when I format tag, it throws IOException. :( `formatable.format(message)`  --> `IOException`

Comment: @Prabs: Ask a separate Stack Overflow question where you provide a [mcve], which would include the full Java stack trace of your crash, plus your code that triggers the crash.